# Windows-сервис использует оперативку и не "отдает" её

Tags: c#, cpu, ram

Я написал SMTP-сервер в виде windows-сервиса. И получается, что после каждого подключившегося клиента, в диспетчере задач он "кушает" на **0,01-0,05 % Memory** на компе.

Из-за чего в принципе в этом случае оперативка может расходоваться?

Гугл говорит, что оперативка нужна для расчетов, вычислений, но, с другой стороны - CPU, по идее, для этих же целей используется.

**На что расходуется оперативка и CPU в работе программы?**

Я думаю, если я пойму, на что расходуется оперативка и проц, я найду решение своего вопроса.

Comment: например вы порождаете кучу стрингов, ну это как вариант, каждая операция со строками плодит новые объекты в памяти

Comment: Спасибо за совет. А стринги надо как-то очищать, когда они не нужны уже?

Comment: Их желательно не плодить :), например не проводить лишние операции конкатинации плюсом, а использовать для этого `StringBuilder`

Comment: А, вот как. А DateTime.Now.ToString() тоже жрет? А создание вообще разных экземпляров классов - тоже его жрет?

Comment: так вы утечки в профайлере поглядите и все станет ясно

Comment: простите, я не смог нагуглить правильно, какой именно профайлер?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms182372.aspx

Comment: спасибо, не знал об этом. а его можно использовать  для виндовс-сервисов?

Comment: Студией цепляйтесь к процессу и профилируйте